# How to validate two xml files are similar (but ignore the element and attribute order)?

Tags: c#, xml, unit-testing

For the purposes of unit testing, I would like to validate that two xml files contain the same data, but ignore the order of the elements or attributes.

I am currently using MbUnit.Framework.Xml.XmlAssert.XmlEquals, and it seems to have a few options but I can't find any documentation.  It returns false if the element order is different.

This is a c# project.

Comment: can you deserialize them into an object and compare the objects? perhaps this proves easier.

Comment: Thanks.  What kind of object?  They are in XDocument objects.  Otherwise, a specific object that represents the data?  It is an interesting suggestion.  We were doing something like that, but there are a lot of different xml files, with different structures, so it hasn't proved very practical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using Microsoft's [XML Diff and Patch Tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302294.aspx).

In addition to the XML Diff and Patch API, you may be interested in taking a look at the Windows Forms code sample that implements the tool - [XML Diff and Patch GUI Tool](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=3471df57-0c08-46b4-894d-f569aa7f7892&displaylang=en) (The API's dll is included in this download).

Answer (score 0):

A while back I was happily using xmlunit for these kinds of problems, http://xmlunit.sourceforge.net/, not sure about the .net side of it, or if it is still kept uptodate &c.